# Через модуль ftputil нужно подключиться к ftp, открыть уже существующий файл с записями и в конец этих записей добавить новые

Tags: python, ftp

Я использовал для этого модуль ftputil, но столкнулся с проблемой, что он не поддерживает 'a'(append) добавление в файл, а если записывать через 'w' он перезаписывает содержимое.

Вот что пробовал и на этом застопорился:

```
    with ftputil.FTPHost(host, ftp_user, ftp_pass) as ftp_host:
      with ftp_host.open("мой_путь_к_файлу_на_сервере", "a") as fobj:
         cupone_wr = input('Введи купоны через пробел: ')
         cupone_wr = cupone_wr.split(' ')
         for x in range(0, len(cupone_wr)):
             cupone_str = '<p>Твой купон %s</p>\n' % cupone_wr[x]
             data = fobj.write(cupone_str)
         print(data)
```

Задача стоит в том, чтобы оставить старые записи в файле и добавлять в конец файла каждый раз при новом вызове скрипта свежие записи.
Очень буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: сначала прочитать содержимое файла в переменную, а потом записать эту переменную + ваши данные

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, пожалуйста, напиши пример как это сделать

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы сделать то, что вам требуется нужно сначала прочитать содержимое файла в переменную, а потом записать эту переменную + ваши новые данные в файл.

```py
cupone_wr = 'smth'
with ftputil.FTPHost(host, ftp_user, ftp_pass) as ftp_host:
      with ftp_host.open("мой_путь_к_файлу_на_сервере", "r") as fobj:
         lines = f.readlines() # считываем строки из файла в список
         lines.append(cupone_wr) # добавляем в конец списка ваш купон
      with ftp_host.open("мой_путь_к_файлу_на_сервере", "w") as fobj: # открываем файл на запись
         for l in lines:
            fobj.write(l) # проходя циклом по списку каждую строку записываем в файл
```